# mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 3 drives - not enough to start the array

Tags: linux, centos, mdadm, raid5

I had a drive in my raid5 fail a while back. I believe the problem was due to a power failure at the time, but originally thought it might be the hard drive controllers on the motherboard (this is a system I put together myself).

Since then, I built a replacement system and transferred the drives over and attempted to start them up. What I'm getting now is that one drive is still not good for the system to start.

Here is what I get when trying to assemble:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sda1 -v
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sda1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 3.
mdadm: added /dev/sde1 to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdd1 to /dev/md0 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sda1 to /dev/md0 as 3 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 8 of /dev/md0
mdadm: added /dev/sdf1 to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 3 drives - not enough to start the array.
```

When I examine the drives, I get this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[a-z]1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 491fdb85:372da78e:8022a675:04a2932c
           Name : kenya:0
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 21 14:18:41 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813527552 (7451.56 GiB 8001.05 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262072 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 879d0ddf:9f9c91c5:ffb0185f:c69dd71f

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Feb  5 06:05:09 2015
       Checksum : 758a6362 - correct
         Events : 624481

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb1.

/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 491fdb85:372da78e:8022a675:04a2932c
           Name : kenya:0
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 21 14:18:41 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813527552 (7451.56 GiB 8001.05 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262072 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3a403437:9a1690ea:f6ce8525:730d1d9c

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Feb  5 06:07:11 2015
       Checksum : 355d0e32 - correct
         Events : 624485

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 491fdb85:372da78e:8022a675:04a2932c
           Name : kenya:0
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 21 14:18:41 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813527552 (7451.56 GiB 8001.05 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262072 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 7d7ec5fe:b4b55c4e:4e903357:1aa3bae3

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Feb  5 06:07:11 2015
       Checksum : da06428d - correct
         Events : 624485

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 491fdb85:372da78e:8022a675:04a2932c
           Name : kenya:0
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 21 14:18:41 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 7813527552 (7451.56 GiB 8001.05 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262072 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c091025f:8296517b:0237935f:5cc03cfc

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Feb  5 06:07:11 2015
       Checksum : 8819fa93 - correct
         Events : 624485

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdg1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :       808960 sectors at            0 (type 17)
```

and then there's this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] [linear]
unused devices: <none>
```

I gathered this info from booting into recovery. The system is centos 6.2. I have learned from some irc help that the sda drive is out of sync with the rest of them. I believe the drive which had failed is now listed as sdg, but i'm not certain of that. I also know the order to the drives is now feda (sdf, sde, sdd, sda).

I have a replacement drive for the dead one ready for insertion when I can get the rest of this built. I was originally going to try to list it as removed from the array, but I cannot get that status to take.

My attempt to sign up for and use the linux-raid mailing list have left me wondering if it is even active anymore. ("delivery to linux-raid-approval@vger.kernel.org has failed permanently.") the help from the centos irc channel suggested getting further help from that source. I'm now trying here.

I also have read through this post but wanted to ask in another forum for a more specific opinion before attempting any of the suggestions toward the end of the thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276699.

If there is a working email thread for mdadm or linux-raid, I'm willing to post there. If more data about this situation can be provided, please let me know.

Comment: mdadm sees that sda1 has a different Events number and assumes it is out of date. It would fix things by syncing but since one disk is missing it can't. That's why it shows only three out of five disks available and can't start the array. There are ways to use --zero-superblock and --assume-clean to force recreation of the array, since the numbers are very close

Comment: zeroing the super blocks is what the ubuntu forums link discusses. i have been considering that possibility, but it sounds like a final step in the attempts to restore the drives. i was looking for any other opinions before i walked down that road...which is probably the course of action i will be end up taking.

Comment: It certainly seems like one. If there is any other way, I would do that but at least I can't find and don't know of any other method unfortunately.

Comment: i am probably going to attempt to back up the individual drives (via dd) in case i really screw things up when executing the zero superblocks argument. i will report back when i have that completed. thanks for the advice.

Comment: ok, backed everything up and zeroed out the superblocks on `/dev/sd[feda]1`. i then was able to create the array using: `# mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 --assume-clean /dev/sdf1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sda1`.  now: `# cat /proc/mdstat` gives me: `Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] [linear] 
md0 : active raid5 sda1[3] sdd1[2] sde1[1] sdf1[0]
      5860147200 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk`

Comment: the array is put back together. i just now have a problem with LVM not being happy with things, but i think that's a separate matter. i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the fact that you're backing up the drives using `dd` is a good thing—a very sensible first action.

You can see from the events counter and the last update timestamp that sda dropped out of the array, but not much changed between when it dropped out and the last access. You can also see the device states on sda say 0–3 are active, 4 missing (mdadm counts from 0); on the other drives, 0–2 active, 3 & 4 missing. So you suffered a second disk failure on RAID5, which of course stopped the array.

So basically you need to ask `mdadm` to ignore the fact that sda is outdated, and assemble the array anyway. Which is what `--force` does—so that *should* have worked. It's possible you just need to add `--run` (or use `--scan`). I think that's what's happening here.

Another possibility is that the boot scripts have half-assembled the array, making devices busy. Check (e.g., `cat` or `less`) `/proc/mdstat` to make sure that hasn't happened, and `mdadm --stop` any unwanted arrays present.

You could also add `--verbose` to get a better idea of why mdadm isn't assembling the array.

Once the array is assembled, you can use `mdadm -a` to add your new disk to it, and a rebuild should start immediately. You should also consider replacing sda, as it'd appear to be flaky (it dropped out before).

In any case, zeroing a superblock is a drastic, near-last-ditch approach to recovering an array. It shouldn't be needed here.